# HttpContext.Request.Form has value, null when assigned to variable

Tags: c#, httpcontext, ihttphandler

I am at a loss. We have a class that handles callbacks from client-side actions

```
jQuery.ajax({data: data, error: null, success: null, type: "POST", dataType: 'json', url: "/mylogger.axd"});.
```

I assign HttpContext.Request.Form to a variable. Though it is non-null, and has all the parameters I expect, the variable I assigned it to is null.

```
public class MyLogger : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        NameValueCollection formParams = context.Request.Form;

        if (formParams == null)
        { ...
```

If I attach Visual Studio to the process, when this gets fired, context.Request.Form definitely has a value:

```
{response=http%3a%2f%2fXXX.XXXcom%2fproduct%2f12345%2f13528311&event=MYEVENT&objid=13528311&objtype=2}  System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase {System.Web.HttpValueCollection}
```

And yet, formParams is null.

Huh? In general, is there any reason why the value wouldn't be copied into the variable?

Comment: Please, provide further details on your implementation... I have tried here and it is never null, even if I have no Forms at all. In the case of the absence of the form the collection is there, with no elements inside, but not null.